# Работа в Notepad++: при открытии новой страницы HTML искажается текст

Tags: кодировка, html

Почему при открытии новой страницы HTML в Notepad++ искажается текст (превращается в символы) пример:

```
<ul>
    <li>Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ</li>
    <li>РЈРЅРёРІРµСЂ</li>
    <li>Р РµР°Р»СЊРЅС‹Рµ РїР°С†Р°РЅС‹</li>
    <li>РРЅС‚РµСЂРЅС‹</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: это скорее всего связано с кодировкой - <meta charset="utf-8"> - в head должно быть, ну или другая кодировка windows-1251

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в кодировке ***файла HTML***, которая не поддерживает кириллицу или т.п. символы.
Скорее всего, Вы делаете ***страницы HTML*** в другом редакторе, а после, открываете его в **Notepad++**, а он в свою очередь, установив кодировку указанную в вашем файле, не может верно отобразить ваш текст.

Вам надо в вашем редакторе (там, где вы верстаете **HTML**), в настройках, установить кодировку по умолчанию, к примеру: **UTF-8**

В **Notepad++**:
(меню сверху)"Опции"->"Настройки..." ->(слева, в списке)"Новый документ" ->(справа, список)отметьте **UTF-8 без BOM**

Чтобы перекодировать текущий файл в **Notepad++**:
(меню сверху)"Кодировки" -> "Переобразовать в UTF-8 (без BOM)"

Answer (score 3):

наконец то нашёл (до всего приходиться доходить самому:-)

"настройки"- "опции"- "новые документ" поставить uft-8 и так же при загрузке ansii.

Answer (score 2):

1. В верхнем меню выбираете пункт «Кодировки», подпункт «Преобразовать в UTF-8 (без ВОМ)»
2. Результатом этого действия будет надпись в правом нижнем углу редактора: ANSI as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Опции->Настройки->Разное->Авто-определение кодировки символов: убрать галку

Answer (score 0):

поставьте плагин AutoCodepage, там добавьте к нужным расширениям нужные кодировки